# Find duplicates in google site map

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, xpath

I want to find any duplicates in my google site map based on loc element.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:s chemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <url><loc>http://mysite.net/Members.aspx</loc><lastmod>2011-07-01</lastmod></url>      
  <url><loc>http://mysite.net/Topics.aspx</loc><lastmod>2011-05-27</lastmod></url>
  <url><loc>http://mysite.net/Members.aspx</loc><lastmod>2011-07-02</lastmod></url>      
</urlset>
```

Sample LINQ:

```
            var duplicates = (from req in doc.Descendants("urlset")
                          group req by req.Descendants("//loc").First().Value
                              into g
                              where g.Count() > 1
                          select g.Skip(1)).SelectMany(elements => elements
                        );
```

How come duplicates returns empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query isn't finding the elements because you didn't specify the namespace. It's also more complex than necessary:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
var duplicates =
    from loc in doc.Root.Elements(ns + "url").Elements(ns + "loc")
    group loc by loc.Value into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

`doc.Descendants("urlset")` will only ever return one element (the `<urlset>`).

You need to select the `<url>` elements:

```
from u in doc.Descendants("url")
group u by u.Element("loc").Value into g
from elem in g.Skip(1)    //This is the SelectMany()
select elem
```